# How to specifiy a selected contenteditable tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing an online Sudoku game and I want to change the background color of each cell , when the user select a cell. For example when I select a cell that contains "4", each cell with "4" value in it must become red, and after changing selected cell, background of each cell with "4" value changes to the default background(here is white).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNF6D.jpg)

**Note** that each `<td> </td>` represents a cell. and selecting a cell means mouse cursor in that cell.

1. How can I specify which cell is selected by user ? (mouse cursor is
   inside of it )
2. How can I specify which cell is hovered by user ? (mouse cursor on
   it )

**More info :**

The HTML summary of Sudoku table is like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
      <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `focus` and `blur` events

```js
$('table').on('focus input', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
  $('td[contenteditable]').css('background-color', '');
  var val = this.textContent;
  if (val) {
    $('td[contenteditable]:contains(' + val + ')').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
$('table').on('blur', '[contenteditable]', function() {
  $('td[contenteditable]').css('background-color', '');
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the difference between `focus` and `focus input` ? @Rayon

Comment: @MMKY, `input` is a different event which will invoke when content inside `contenteditable` is changed..

Answer (score 2):

You could use `click()` event to detect selected cell and `input` event to detect user change inside the input, then use `each()` to go through all cells and colorize the matched ones, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet Example

```js
$('table').on('click input','td',function(){
  var clicked_td_text = $(this).text();

  $('td').each(function(){
    if( clicked_td_text!='' && $(this).text()==clicked_td_text )
      $(this).addClass('red');
    else
      $(this).removeClass('red');
  })

})
```

```css
.red{
   background-color: red !important;
}
table td{
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

table td[contenteditable="false"]{
   background-color: #E8F7E6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">5</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">5</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">6</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">7</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">1</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">3</td>    
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">5</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">7</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="false">6</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: It it correct , but not useful for me, because i dont have direct access to css file :)